# Why favourites are not shown in main page of questions?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks, question-lists

When we view the questions and then only there is how many favorites added for the question we can see. But why not the favorites are not shown in the questions before viewing them. There is only votes for the questions and how many answers are there.

Comment: Because votes and number of answers are more important.

Comment: I think that's the main difference between Listing Page and Detail Page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply not important enough to be included in the questions list. Usually those who favorite also upvote, so question with lots of "followers" will have lots of upvotes, and this does appear in the list.

If you're interesting to analyze questions by the amount of users favoriting them, you have the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), I just created a quick query to show top 100 favorited questions on Stack Overflow: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155952/see-top-100-favorites-questions

(note that DE data is not  live but rather updated weekly, so the numbers might be bit off)